# Display SnackBar in Flutter

Tags: dart, android-snackbar, snackbar, flutter

I want to display a **simple `SnackBar` inside Flutter**'s Stateful widget. My application creates new instance of *`MaterialApp`* with a stateful widget called *`MyHomePage`*.

I try to show the **SnackBar** in `showSnackBar()` method. But it fails with *`The method showSnackBar was called on null`*.

What's wrong with this code?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showInSnackBar("Some text");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: new Text("Simple Text")
    );
  }

  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        content: new Text(value)
    ));
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter',
        theme: new ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(body: new MyHomePage()),
      );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    showInSnackBar("Some text");
    return new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Scaffold(
          body: new Text("Simple Text")
        )
    );
  }

  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        content: new Text(value)
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: i would rather suggest all the flutter users to use flushbar plugin . You can look at this answer why you should use flushbar plugin instead of directly using snackbar. go look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51261864/7940500

Comment: Just use an async function to call your snackbar, if you put your function in build instead of initstate you will get the snackbar popping up each time there's a setstate

Comment: Here is a tutorial video on how to make the SnackBar widget available to any page, if you are quite confused: https://youtu.be/u9KoFtu0HEY

Comment: `Scaffold.of()` is deprecated for showing SnackBars, use [ScaffoldMessenger](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) instead.

Comment: u may try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69344954/4153682

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's three problems. The first is that you don't have a Scaffold anywhere, and the Scaffold widget is the one that knows how to show snack bars. The second is that you have a key for getting a hold of the scaffold, but you've put it on a Padding instead (and Paddings don't have any knowledge of snack bars). The third is that you've used the key before the widget that it's associated with has had a chance to be initialised, since initState is called before build.

The simplest solution is to change the `home` line in your MyApp widget to:

`home: new Scaffold(body: new MyHomePage()),`

...and then remove all mention of `_scaffoldKey` and instead use `Scaffold.of(context)` where you currently have `_scaffoldKey.currentState`.

Comment: wrapping my StatefulWidget with a new `Scaffold` and using `Scaffold.of(context)` instead of the `_scaffoldKey` reference helps. Thanks!

Comment: Having nested `Scaffold`s is _strongly_ discouraged, so be careful here!

Comment: @Westy92, It's interesting comments, could you please show us why? I have seen someone encouraged to use scaffold wrapping every widget, but I don't believe, tho.

Comment: @Tokenyet https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/26259/files#diff-ad7e5ee7be5375e4242652ddc6448da7R729

Answer (score 76):

In my case i had code like this (in class state)

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(value)));
}
```

but i didn't setup the key for scaffold.
so  when i add **key: _scaffoldKey**

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: new SafeArea(
```

snackbar start to work :)

Comment: The Flutter documentation describes this as "A less elegant but more expedient solution..". Please tread carefully :)

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L1364

Comment: That's the perfect use case for ScaffoldKey!

Comment: showSnackBar method not founded on currentState

Answer (score 42):

#### `ScaffoldState` is now deprecated. Use `ScaffoldMessengerState`.

There are generally two ways of showing the `SnackBar` using `ScaffoldMessenger`.

---

1. **Direct way:**

   ```dart
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () {
           var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hello World'));
           ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
         },
         child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
       ),
     );
   }
   ```

---

2. **Using `GlobalKey`.**

   ```
   final _globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ScaffoldMessenger(
       key: _globalKey,
       child: Scaffold(
         body: Center(
           child: ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: () {
               var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hello World'));
               _globalKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
             },
             child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: don't know why Direct way is not working for me!! in Global way. 
did not also work in this way rather i have found a better solution somewhere else

SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Please fill all fields'),backgroundColor:Colors.red ,);
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!).showSnackBar(snackBar);

Answer (score 33):

There's a better and cleaner way to display a Snackbar in flutter. I found it the hard way and sharing so that maybe it's helpful for someone else.

No need to change in your main app part

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'MyApp',
    theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
    home: new MainPage());
  }
}
```

**Page State code is where things will change.**

We know Flutter provides `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar`. However, the context should be the context of a descendant of a Scaffold, and not the context that includes a Scaffold. In order to avoid error, we need to use a BuildContext for the body of the Scaffold, and store it in a variable, as below.

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {                                                                         
BuildContext scaffoldContext;                                                                                                                                                                                                

@override                                                                                                           
Widget build(BuildContext context) {                                                                                

return new Scaffold(                                                                                              
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,                                                                                 
    appBar: new AppBar(                                                                                           
      title: const Text(APP_TITLE),                                                                               
    ),                                                                                                             
    body: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {                                                           
      scaffoldContext = context;                                                                                  
      return new Center(
           child: new Text('Hello World', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
         );                                                                                
    }));                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                   


void createSnackBar(String message) {                                                                               
  final snackBar = new SnackBar(content: new Text(message),                                                         
  backgroundColor: Colors.red);                                                                                      

  // Find the Scaffold in the Widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar!                                            
  Scaffold.of(scaffoldContext).showSnackBar(snackBar);                                                              
  }                                                                                                                   
}
```

Now, you can call this function from anywhere and it will display the Snackbar. For example, I am using it to display Internet Connectivity messages.

Comment: How this one is better than approach with GlobalKey provided by @Jack the Ripper?

Comment: Because GlobalKey is expensive. See this answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304568/scaffold-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-scaffold

Answer (score 14):

you can use this :

```
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(


    ),
  }
}
```

and then
in `onPressed()` can add this code

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
       new SnackBar(
          content: new Text('Hello this is snackbar!')
       )
);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
     SnackBar(content: Text("Thanks for using snackbar",
     textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: 
     FontWeight.bold),), duration: Duration(seconds: 2), backgroundColor: Colors.red,)
);
```

Answer (score 10):

To initialise a Snackbar on initState() you can execute a function after the layout is built.

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance
    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Your message here..")));}
```

Answer (score 7):

`initState` been called before `build` I guess `_scaffoldKey.currentState` has not been initialized when it is call.

I don't know if you can get a `ScaffoldState` from `initState`. If you change your code you can show the snackbar from `build` method with:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(Text(value)));
```

Comment: simply moving the `method showInSnackBar()` to build() does NOT help. On one hand you're right - initState() is called before the build() method, but even after initState() methods:   `Scaffold.of(context)` as well as field `_scaffoldKey.currentState` are null.

Answer (score 6):

`Scaffold.Of(context)` is deprecated for showing snackbar.

use the new way:

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

[**`snackbars`**](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars)

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is looking to initialise a `Snackbar` on `initState()` (in other words when the page loads here is my solution). Also, I assume you already have the `_scaffoldKey` in place.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(
    (_) => _displaySnackbar
  );
}

// Display Snackbar
void get _displaySnackbar {
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(minutes: 1),
    content: Text('Your snackbar message')
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in three simple steps.

1. Make sure you have a key for scaffold. You can create that by writing the below code:

   ```
   final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
   ```

2.Now you have to mention this key inside your Scaffold, by writing the below line inside scaffold:

```
key:_scaffoldKey,
```

3. Now you can show snackbar by writing:

   ```
   final snackBar=SnackBar(
                         content: Text('Your password has been changed successfully'),
                       );
                       _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
   ```

Answer (score 4):

**ScaffoldState is now deprecated. Use ScaffoldMessengerState.**

All the above solutions are amazing but as it's deprecated now you should use it this way.

```
    var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hello World'));

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext)
    .showSnackBar(snackBar );
```

Comment: Hi, I've already written this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64617970/6618622). There's no benefit in adding the same thing twice.

Comment: If I saw your answer in the time I wrote this, I wouldn't waste my time writing a duplicate answer. have a nice day

Comment: I just remove the `Builder` from my answer in the edit. Rest of the things are exactly the same, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

We can use like this

**

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text("Enter your phone number"),
                        ),
                      );
```

**

Answer (score 2):

**Display SnackBar in Flutter**

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('Please Enter Valid Data'),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                ));
```

Example:

```
 if(value.isNotEmpty && value != null){
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('Validated Successfully'),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                ));
}else{
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('Please Enter Valid Data'),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a PageWrapper that you can wrap all of your pages to get the context of the Scaffold widget and avoid experiencing these errors again.

Here is a sample of the page wrapper:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageWrapper extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget page;

  WPage(this.page);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: page
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can wrap all your pages in the main.dart like these:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/login',
  routes: {
    '/login': (context) => PageWrapper(Login()),
    '/home': (context) => PageWrapper(Home())
  }
));
```

Now you can call `Scaffold.of(context)` anywhere in any page just fine.

Reference: https://noobieprogrammer.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-create-error-alert-or-popup.html

or watch the video version (5 min. long): https://youtu.be/u9KoFtu0HEY

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside a widget that does not has directly the `return Scaffold(...)` widget, you can do this:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Hello from snackbar")));
```

There is no need to create an extra Scaffold widget because the `showSnackBar()` method requires one, you can reuse.

Answer (score 0):

In the null safety version--

```
class _testPageState extends State<testPage> {

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

        home: SizedBox(
            child: Scaffold(

                key: _scaffoldKey,

                body: Center(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {

                        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Your Text'));    
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(snackBar);

                      },

                      child: Text("Show SB"),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package snackbar

customsnackbar: ^0.0.1

showCustomSnackBar("Hello", 10.0 ,5, Colors.white);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: Text('SnackBar Message')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: "pressed".text.make(),
              ));
            },
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?