# Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar, scaffold

As you can see, my button is inside the `Scaffold`'s body. But I get this exception:

*Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SnackBar Playground'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.pink,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: _displaySnackBar(context),
          child: Text('Display SnackBar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_displaySnackBar(BuildContext context) {
  final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Are you talkin\' to me?'));
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

EDIT:

I found another solution to this problem. If we give the `Scaffold` a key which is the `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>`, we can display the SnackBar as following without the need to wrap our body within the `Builder` widget. The widget which returns the `Scaffold` should be a Stateful widget though.

```
 _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
```

Comment: I found a very good tutorial where he made a wrapper so that he can easily change or control the context of the whole app: https://noobieprogrammer.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-create-error-alert-or-popup.html

Answer (score 467, accepted):

This exception happens because you are using the `context` of the widget that instantiated `Scaffold`. Not the `context` of a child of `Scaffold`.

You can solve this by just using a different context :

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SnackBar Playground'),
    ),
    body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => 
            Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.pink,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () => _displaySnackBar(context),
            child: Text('Display SnackBar'),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Note that while we're using `Builder` here, this is not the only way to obtain a different `BuildContext`.

It is also possible to extract the subtree into a different `Widget` (usually using `extract widget` refactor)

Comment: I thought with .of(context) it's supposed to travel up the widget hierarchy until it encounters one of the given type, in this case, Scaffold, which it should encounter before it reaches "Widget build(..". Does it not work this way?

Comment: @RémiRousselet, How many types of context are there in Flutter? Like you said context of widget, context of a child of Scaffold.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Only one. Scaffold is a widget too.

Comment: @CodeGrue it does work that way, but the `context` being passed to `Scaffold.of()` was "above" the `Scaffold` in the hierarchy, since it was the context passed to `HomePage.build()`

Comment: the code from question is same as the official docs (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars)  which doesn't use Builder, is it a bug in offical documentation?

Comment: `Builder` is not the only way obtain a different `BuildContext`.

Comment: @RémiRousselet What are other ways to obtain a different BuildContext? I can think of using GlobalKeys, but what are some more?

Comment: Split your widget into multiple ones.

Comment: For an updated approach, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692274/638153) by @Deczaloth. "[The new approach](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) calls on the `ScaffoldMessenger` to show the SnackBar. In this case, the `Builder` is no longer required to provide a new scope with a BuildContext that is 'under' the Scaffold."

Comment: do not forget to add : 'drawer: NavigationDrawer()'

Answer (score 198):

You can use a `GlobalKey`. The only downside is that using GlobalKey might not be the most efficient way of doing this.

A good thing about this is that you can also pass this key to other custom widgets class that do not contain any scaffold. See([here](https://youtu.be/SY3bX3VN-HY))

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); \\ new line
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,                           \\ new line
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SnackBar Playground'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.pink,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: _displaySnackBar(context),
          child: Text('Display SnackBar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  _displaySnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Are you talkin\' to me?'));
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);   \\ edited line
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask  how to replicate this when your tree is comprised of multiple widgets defined in multiple files? `_scaffoldKey` is private due to the leading underscore. But even if it weren't, it is inside the `HomePage` class and therefore unavailable without instantiating a new HomePage somewhere down the tree, seemingly creating a circular reference.

Comment: to answer my own question: create a singleton class with a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` property, edit the constructor of the Widget with the scaffold to set the singleton's key property, then in the child widget's tree we can call something like `mySingleton.instance.key.currentState.showSnackBar()` ...

Comment: Why is this inefficient?

Comment: @user2233706 This is mentioned in the documentation of GlobalKey [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html). Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329065/builder-versus-globalkey) might shed more light.

Comment: `_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);   ` has been depreciated.

Comment: Regarding deprecation: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692274/638153) by @Deczaloth. The [new approach](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) calls on the `ScaffoldMessenger` to show the SnackBar.

Answer (score 91):

You can solve this problem in two ways:

**1) Using Builder widget**

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Profile'),
    ),
    body: Builder(
        builder: (ctx) => RaisedButton(
            textColor: Colors.red,
            child: Text('Submit'),
            onPressed: () {
                 Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Save'),),);
            }               
        ),
    ),
);
```

**2) Using GlobalKey**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       key: globalKey,
       appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Profile'),
       ),
       body:  RaisedButton(
          textColor: Colors.red,
          child: Text('Submit'),
          onPressed: (){
               final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Profile saved'));
               globalKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },
        ),
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: Both approached have been depreciated.

Comment: @Pankaj Would you happen to have a source on both of these being deprecated? The `Builder` widget class is the top accepted answer, and the 2nd top answer uses `GlobalKey` (which has been noted _can_ be "expensive" as well as a reactive antipattern). And although this answer appears redundant to the top two answers, I can't seem to find a reference to either being deprecated. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: For the first solution, I do know `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(mySnackBar);` [has been replaced by](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(mySnackBar);`. Is that what you were referring to with solution 1 being deprecated? EDIT: Oh! Is this why? "...In this case, the Builder is no longer required to provide a new scope with a BuildContext that is 'under' the Scaffold."

Comment: Never mind. I found [the extended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692274/638153) by @Deczaloth below. Glad I caught your comment though.

Answer (score 35):

### UPDATE - 2021

> `Scaffold.of(context)` is deprecated in favor of `ScaffoldMessenger`.

Check this from the documentation of method:

> The **ScaffoldMessenger** now handles **SnackBars** in order to persist across
> routes and always be displayed on the current Scaffold. By default, a
> root **ScaffoldMessenger** is included in the **MaterialApp**, but you can
> create your own controlled scope for the **ScaffoldMessenger** to further
> control which Scaffolds receive your SnackBars.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Demo')
    ),
    body: Builder(
      // Create an inner BuildContext so that the onPressed methods
      // can refer to the Scaffold with Scaffold.of().
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
         return Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('SHOW A SNACKBAR'),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Hello!'),
              ));
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

You can check the detailed deprecation and new approach [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger):

Answer (score 19):

Simple way to solving this issue will be creating a key for your scaffold like this final with the following code:

First:  `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>() _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>
();`

Scecond: Assign the Key to your Scaffold `key: _scaffoldKey`

Third: Call the Snackbar using
`_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Welcome")));`

Comment: Both approached have been depreciated

Comment: Regarding deprecation: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692274/638153) by @Deczaloth. "[The new approach](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) calls on the `ScaffoldMessenger` to show the SnackBar.

Answer (score 19):

### UPDATE: recommended approach by Flutter (as of 20.12.2022)...

To show a Snackbar you should be using:

### [ScaffoldMessenger](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger)

From [the docu](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) we read

> The SnackBar API within the Scaffold is now handled by the ScaffoldMessenger, one of which is available by default within the context of a MaterialApp

So, with **ScaffoldMessenger** now you will be able to write code like

```dart
Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: const Text('snack'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'ACTION',
          onPressed: () { },
        ),
      ));
    },
    child: const Text('SHOW SNACK'),
  ),
);
```

Now, again in the docu we can see that

> When presenting a SnackBar during a transition, the SnackBar will complete a Hero animation, moving smoothly to the next page.
>
> The ScaffoldMessenger creates a scope in which all descendant Scaffolds register to receive SnackBars, which is how they persist across these transitions. When using the root ScaffoldMessenger provided by the MaterialApp, all descendant Scaffolds receive SnackBars, unless a new ScaffoldMessenger scope is created further down the tree. By instantiating your own ScaffoldMessenger, you can control which Scaffolds receive SnackBars, and which do not based on the context of your application.

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

*The very behavior you are experiencing is even referred to as a "tricky case" in the **Flutter** [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html).*

### How To Fix

The issue is fixed in different ways as you can see from other answers posted here. For instance, the piece of documentation i refer to solves the issue by using a `Builder` which creates

> an inner `BuildContext` so that the `onPressed` methods can refer to the `Scaffold` with `Scaffold.of()`.

Thus a way to call `showSnackBar` from **Scaffold** would be

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
    body: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
        return FlatButton(
          child: Text('BUTTON'),
          onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(innerContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('Hello.')
            ));
          }
        );
      }
    )
  );
}
```

### Now some detail for the curious reader

*I myself found quite instructive to explore the **Flutter** documentation by simply (**Android Studio**) setting the cursor on a piece of code (**Flutter** class, method, etc.) and pressing ctrl+B to be shown the documentation for that specific piece.*

The particular problem you are facing is mentioned in the docu for **BuildContext**, where can be read

> Each widget has its own **BuildContext**, which becomes the parent of the widget returned by the [...].build function.

So, this means that in our case *context* **will be** the parent of our Scaffold widget **when it is created** (!). Further, the docu for **Scaffold.of** says that it returns

> The state from the closest [**Scaffold**] instance of this class that encloses the given context.

But in our case, *context* does not encloses (yet) a **Scaffold** (it has not yet been built). There is where **Builder** comes into action!

Once again, the docu illuminates us. There we can read

> [The Builder class, is simply] A platonic widget that calls a closure to obtain its child widget.

Hey, wait a moment, what!? Ok, i admit: that is not helping a lot... But it is enough to say (following [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088889/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-the-builder-class-does-in-flutter)) that

> The purpose of the **Builder** class is simply to build and return child widgets.

So now it all becomes clear! By calling **Builder** inside **Scaffold** we are building the Scaffold in order to be able to obtain its own context, and armed with that *innerContext* we can finally call **Scaffold.of(innerContext)**

An annotated version of the code above follows

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // here, Scaffold.of(context) returns null
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
    body: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
        return FlatButton(
          child: Text('BUTTON'),
          onPressed: () {
            // here, Scaffold.of(innerContext) returns the locally created Scaffold
            Scaffold.of(innerContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('Hello.')
            ));
          }
        );
      }
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Use `ScaffoldMessenger` (Recommended)

```dart
var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hi there'));
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

---

#### Example (Without `Builder` or `GlobalKey`)

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hello World'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    },
    child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 12):

From Flutter version 1.23-18.1.pre you can use ScaffoldMessenger

```dart
final mainScaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      scaffoldMessengerKey: mainScaffoldMessengerKey
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Somewhere inside app:

```dart
mainScaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(Snackbar(...));
```

Answer (score 7):

A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets.
This introduce a 'new context', from which you can obtain Scaffold

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Scaffold.of example.')),
        body: MyScaffoldBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffoldBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Show a snackBar'),
          onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text('Have a Snack'),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I may be late. But this will help someone too.
Add a **_key** under the **Scaffold**.
Then use that **_key** to call the *openDrawer* method.

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey, //this is the key
  endDrawer: Drawer(),
  appBar: AppBar( 
//all codes for appbar here
actions: [
IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        onPressed: () {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer(); // this is it
       
        },
      ),]
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't bother using the default snackbar, because you can import a flushbar package, which enables greater customizability:

https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

For example:

```
Flushbar(
                  title:  "Hey Ninja",
                  message:  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
                  duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),              
                )..show(context);
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there is a solution in this code.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("SnackBar Message")));
```

Answer (score 3):

here we use a builder to wrap in another widget where we need snackbar

```dart
Builder(builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('Your Services have been successfully created Snackbar'),
        ));
        
    },
    child: Container(...)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
           Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                          content: Text("added to cart"),
                           action: SnackBarAction(
                            label: 'Undo',
                             onPressed: () {
                              // Some code to undo the change.
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                    },
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                    child: Text("Add To Cart",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Singleton.showInSnackBar(
    Scaffold.of(context).context, "Theme Changed Successfully");
// Just use Scaffold.of(context) before context!!
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I had to wrap my widget with `Scaffold`

bonus tip: `backgroundColor:Colors.transparnt`