# StatefulBuilder vs StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

What is the difference between `StatefulBuilder` and `StatefulWidget`? When one should be used instead of the other?
At first glance they seem similar.
`StatefulBuilder` is defined:

> A platonic widget that both has state and calls a closure to obtain its child widget

While `StatefulBuilder` is defined:

> A widget that has mutable state

Answer (score 18):

In general use [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) inline when creating your widget tree in a `build` method. This is usually helpful when you need access to a `context` in your widgets subtree. for example:
*Also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088889/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-the-builder-class-does-in-flutter)*

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Home"),
       ),
       body: Builder(builder: (thisLowerContext) {
         return RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(thisLowerContext)
                 .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("button was clicked"))));
       }));
 }
```

Use [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) when you need access to the [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) of that subtree. This will rebuild only the `StatefulBuilder` with its subtree.

```
class _SomeWidgetState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Data data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: StatefulBuilder(builder: (thisLowerContext, innerSetState) {
          if (data == null) {
            return RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Load data"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Scaffold.of(thisLowerContext)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Loading data...")));
                  var loadedData = await _loadData();
                  innerSetState(() => data = loadedData);
                });
          } else {
            return RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Reload data"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Scaffold.of(thisLowerContext).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text("Reloading data...")));
                  var loadedData = await _reloadData();
                  innerSetState(() => data = loadedData);
                });
          }
        }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `StatefulBuilder` this way is not very recommended. Consider using InheritedWidgets or ValueNotifier instead.

Comment: @RémiRousselet amazing! Thanks for the tip. Never used ValueNotifier along with ValueListenableBuilder before but it's perfect for something like this and simple.