# Show snackbar when item is tapped in bottom sheet

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to show `Snackbar` when an item is clicked in the bottom sheet. I tried this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext defaultContext) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
              context: defaultContext,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("Click me"),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(builderContext); // hiding bottom sheet
                        Scaffold.of(builderContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Hi")));
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

But I am having error

> Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold

**Note** The question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304568/scaffold-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-scaffold/51304732)

PS: I know I can use `GlobalKey` in `Scaffold` to show the `Snackbar` but I want to do it using `Builder` like the [docs suggest](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html) to use `Builder`. I did use builder and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked out finally.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext defaultContext) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Builder(builder: (builderContext) {
        return RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: defaultContext,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("Click me"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(builderContext); // hiding bottom sheet
                  Scaffold.of(builderContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Hi")));
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },),
    ),
  );
}
```

I need to move `Builder` up the tree. Don't know the reason why but it worked.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why shifting `Builder` up the tree made it work?

Comment: It finds closest Scaffold above, inside closest context (context1) from contextMy. While your wrong sample finds it inside context2/RaisedButton, which is none.

Comment: @mnemonic23 Thanks but my naming convention was too bad, I updated the convention and formatted the code, can you now tell me using updated names.

Comment: The idea is, you have to place 'Builder' somewhere below Scaffold but still IN THE SAME BuildContext where Scaffold is (which is defaultContext). The error occur because you place 'Builder' inside another context (which is belong to showModalBottomSheet).

Comment: I think this explain why we need additional Builder to make showSnackBar worked. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html

Comment: @mnemonic23 I was also getting the feeling to place the `Builder` somewhere below the `Scaffold` ... thanks for your tip.