# How to programmatically open a Drawer by tapping on a BottomNavigationBarItem?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making a flutter app and I need to be able to open the Drawer by tapping on a BottomNavigationBarItem. Is there any way to do that?

The UX designer guy put the drawer menu icon at index 0 in the bottom navigation bar. I tried to find an answer in the Flutter documentation but I didn't find anything relevant. I actually found a way of opening it programmatically (as you can see below) but it does not work like that in my case.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 1; // 0 = menu

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepPurple),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.white),
    DiagnosisWidget(),
    FindUsWidget(),
  ];

  _navItem(String text, IconData icon) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      /* Building Bottom nav item */
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if(index == 0) {
        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); // This is what I've tried
      }
      else {
        _currentIndex = index;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: MyDrawer(),
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, // 4+ items in the bar
        items: [
          _navItem('MENU', Icons.menu),
          _navItem('HOME', Icons.home),
          _navItem('DIAGNOSIS', Icons.person),
          _navItem('FIND US', Icons.location_on),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of having the Drawer showing up, I get the following error message :

> Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because in `onTabTapped` you use a context that doesn't contain the Scaffold you create.

You instantiate the Scaffold in `build` but in `onTabTapped` you're looking for a parent Scaffold in the current context (`_HomeState` context).

You can use `Builder` inside the Scaffold to get the correct context or use a `GlobalKey` on your Scaffold.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889100/11096288) for more details.

**EDIT:**
In your case a `GlobalKey` is mush easier to implement.

You can do the following :

```dart
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); // ADD THIS LINE
  int _currentIndex = 1; // 0 = menu

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepPurple),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.white),
    DiagnosisWidget(),
    FindUsWidget(),
  ];

  _navItem(String text, IconData icon) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      /* Building Bottom nav item */
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if(index == 0) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(); // CHANGE THIS LINE
      }
      else {
        _currentIndex = index;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey, // ADD THIS LINE
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: MyDrawer(),
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, // 4+ items in the bar
        items: [
          _navItem('MENU', Icons.menu),
          _navItem('HOME', Icons.home),
          _navItem('DIAGNOSIS', Icons.person),
          _navItem('FIND US', Icons.location_on),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```