# Two providers in one Widget - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, state, provider

I have this problem. In my App I'm using the `Provider package` to manage the login State. In the MaterialApp I also want to manage some sort of the user configuration, in this case the Theme selection.

If I try to use two times `Provider.of<LoginService>(context)` I'm receiving this error:

```
 Could not find the correct Provider<LoginService> above this MyApp Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.
```

How can I use in Provider more of one time the `Provider.of...` or even two different Providers in a Widget (to, for instance, separate my `LoginService` and my `UserconfigService`)?

Thank you!

**Actual code:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginService>(
        create: (context) => LoginService(),
        child:  MaterialApp(
          title: 'My App',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData.dark(),
          routes: {
            '/': (BuildContext context) {
              var state = Provider.of<LoginService>(context);
              if (state.isLoggedIn()) {
                return HomeScreen();
              } else {
                return LoginScreen();
              }
            },
            MentorScreen.id: (BuildContext context) => MentorScreen(),
          },
        )
    );

  }
```

**My objective:**

```
child:  MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: state.isDarkThemeEnabled() == true ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiProvider instead of ChangeNotifierProvider.
Read more in [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/63#issuecomment-491962141).

Answer (score 0):

This type of Error comes when you use the `context` just after creating the `ChangeNotifierProvider` class.

Similarly, if you use the `context` of the `Scaffold` to showDialog gives a similar error.
[Here is the answer that explains why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304732/13139719)

For this Wrap, your `MaterialApp` Widget inside `Builder` Class which will wait for the class to build first then call the `Provider.of<T>(context)` method.

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) {
          var state = Provider.of<LoginService>(context);
          if (state.isLoggedIn()) {
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return LoginScreen();
          }
        },
        MentorScreen.id: (BuildContext context) => MentorScreen(),
      },
    );
  },
),
```

and for Two Providers in the same widget.

Use `MultiProvider`.

here's code from one of my app.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider(
    create: (_) => locator<FAuthService>(),
    builder: (context, _) {
      return MultiProvider(
        child: MaterialApp(
          onGenerateRoute: Router.onGenerateRoute,
          initialRoute: initialRoute,
          navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().globalKey,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
           ),
        ),
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<HomeVM>(
            create: (_) => locator<HomeVM>(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginVM>(
            create: (context) => locator<LoginVM>(),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
   }
}
```