# Flutter error : Undefined name 'ScaffoldMessenger'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, syntax-error

Always getting this error on a project without any reason for the moment could you help me on this.

Undefined name 'ScaffoldMessenger'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Flutter version : 1.22.5 stable

Could you help me on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes (at the moment), under *Not yet released to stable*, we see *SnackBars managed by the ScaffoldMessenger*.  So, it's not in 1.22... it'll be in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same error and I tried this and it work

```
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
             content: Text('Some Text'),
                  ),
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are still experiencing this issue you might have to [update your **Flutter** sdk](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading).

**[ScaffoldMessenger](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger)** was first released to **Flutter** *stable channel* the 3th of March 2021...

To update flutter just run

```
flutter upgrade
```

on your terminal/command line.

For further details take a look at [the ScaffoldMessenger documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) or [in StackOverflow see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692274/7432242).

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error that scaffold is not present then, use builder widget to get the context and then use the scaffold.of() part.