# Showing a simple snackbar

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello there I am new to programming. I'm building an app in flutter, but I have some issue with snackbar. I'm building an image with a wrapped button and an `onPressed` method with a print statement that work. I want to put inside the `onPressed` method a snackbar to show a message. I've done the following code:

```
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('Show Snackbar'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          ));
          print('Image pressed.');
        },
```

My button work. But no snackbar show and android studio run the following error:

Compiler message:

```
lib/main.dart:20:27: Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          ^^^^^^^
```

What i have to do, for showing a toast/snackbar once pressed my image?

Comment: Can you post the full widget code here ?

Comment: Follow this link. Many explanations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579879/display-snackbar-in-flutter