# Trying to display a Flutter snackbar throws an exception error

Tags: flutter

Please before mark it as **duplicate** take a look, I have been trying [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579879/display-snackbar-in-flutter) but i can't make it work.
I am trying to make my learning app to display a snackbar, and yes i ran the google cookbook sample and it works, but i am trying to challenge my self doing something else, basically what it is, is just a scaffold with two buttons that increase and decrease, when the index is zero i want to display a snackbar that index is zero, can't decrease more than that. So i got this button and onPressed method calls _onTapPrevious method which passed the context parameter, but i am not sure this is the correct way to pass the context.

```dart
new RaisedButton( 
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  textColor: Colors.white,
  color: Colors.redAccent,
  onPressed: () => _onTapPrevious(context),
  child: new Text("Previous"),
),
```

Here is the _onTapPrevious method that i created a snackbar, and also checks whether the widget index is > than 0 and if so it can decrease the index, and when it reaches 0 then it should display the snackbar.

```dart
_onTapPrevious(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Index 0, can't decrease more."));
    setState(() {
      if (widget.index > 0) {
        widget.index--;
      } else {
       Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
     }
    });
  }
```

The error that i get:

```dart
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

to your class, then in Scaffold:

```
 key: _scaffoldKey,
```

and finally:

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did exactly this, just a moment ago before you wrote this solution, and just when i was deleting this question, it came the notification that you wrote an answer, but thanks man anyway, and i am keeping it and also marking as a solution. :)