# How to show snackBar without Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, snackbar

I am trying to show snackbar in my app to notify User but without scaffold it shows me error. My current code is:

```
scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
    new SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: color ?? Colors.red,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds),
      content: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        child: Center(
          child: new Text(
            title,
            style: AppTheme.textStyle.lightText.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: you probably have a parent widget that contains `Scaffold` as well. Create a `scaffoldKey` for that and pass it to your child `widget` that have to show the `Snakcbar`. Note that you can't use `Sanckbar` without `Scaffold` widget.

Comment: I want to achieve it without the Scaffold. is that achievable?

Comment: No, you can't do that without `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can get the current context and show snackbar like this:

```
void _showToast(BuildContext context) {
  final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);
  scaffold.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: const Text('Updating..'),
    ),
  );
}

this._showToast(context);
```

Comment: You can't show snackbar without context of scaffold.

Comment: looks like it is possible, by creating a global snacker key, check bugzilla's answr

Answer (score 83):

**If you have access to context**, from [laszlo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67123487/13772418), just call

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

---

**If you dont have context** (eg: showing network request error), use this snippet based on answer from [Miguel Ruvio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68847551/13772418)

We are going to use the property scaffoldMessengerKey which allows us to show snackbars without needing context with just one GlobalKey. Also, no need to add 3rd party packages like Get.

---

First, create a globals.dart to store a GlobalKey

```
//globals.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> snackbarKey =
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
```

Second, add scaffoldMessengerKey property to MaterialApp

```
//main.dart

import 'globals.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      scaffoldMessengerKey: snackbarKey, // <= this
      ...
```

Finally, refer to this Key anywhere to show a Snackbar

```
// anywhere

import 'globals.dart';

final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("your snackbar message"));
snackbarKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. works beautifully well if you are using  Provider, MVVM architecture and for whatever reason of yours, you want to create Snackbars from within your viewModel.

Comment: I have seen many solutions with static global scaffold keys but all are not working. This answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is definitely deserving an accepted answer. works like a charm.

Comment: It didn't work and it said it needed a scaffold to show the message.

Comment: @Abhijitleihaorambam can you share some code?

Comment: its ok, I just call the native toast instead of doing it this way and works perfectly.

Comment: This should 100% be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

No, It is not possible. Snackbar is part of Scaffold.
It must have a Scaffold parent. [Snackbar](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars)

Inside Scaffold parent, you can do like below

```
BuildContext con=context;
final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
Scaffold.of(con).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/get

then you can simply call the Get.snackbar() to show the snackbar where you want it to be displayed.

```
Get.snackbar('Hi', 'i am a modern snackbar');
```

**NOTE**

You can use this package when you don't have the context too.

Comment: Do not use Get. It's a huge package that does too many things. Every experienced Flutter Dev will tell you the same.

Answer (score 4):

`Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar()` is **deprecated**. You should use ScaffoldMessenger now.

Example: `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Clicked!")));`

[Here](https://letusflutter.com/2020/11/19/future-of-snackbars-scaffoldmessenger/) are listed the benefits of the new approach.