# Recieving a message from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-messaging

I am making a simple application which uses a `WebView` widget as it's main widget. I want to be able to send a notification to **all** users from the firebase console. The application has **no authentication**.

**My MessageHandler (defined in main.dart)**

```
class MessageHandler extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MessageHandlerState createState() => _MessageHandlerState();
    }
class _MessageHandlerState extends State<MessageHandler>{
    final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
    @override
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _fcm.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("here");
    print("onMessage: $message");
    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message['notification']['title']),
    );
  },
 );
```

**Main**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   // This widget is the root of your application.
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       title: "Simple App",
  home: WebViewer()
);
}
}
```

The WebViewer Widget works so I have not added it to the question. 
On the Firebase Console, the message appears to have been sent

[image: amazon console]

but the alert does not appear on the Android Emulator, nor does the `snackbar`.

**WebView**

```
class WebViewer extends StatelessWidget {
   final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  //FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text("Event Viewer")),
    ),
    body: WebView(
      initialUrl: "https://google.com",
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
    )
);
```

Comment: Where are u accessing the Message Handler inside `webViewer`? Also are the print not appearing?

Comment: @PeterHaddad prints are not appearing, i will edit question to add that code.

Comment: Firebase notifications does not work on Emulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the snackbar, you have to reference the specific scaffold instance that your app has built and tell it to show a snackbar. If the context is handy, you can say Scaffold.of(context).showSnackbar( snackbar ); Since you don't have access to the context, another way to reference the Scaffold is to define a key for the scaffold and then make sure you assign that key to the webviewer's scaffold.

You can say

```
class MessageHandler extends StatefulWidget {
    // pass a reference to the scaffold key to the message handler when it is created
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;
    MessageHandler({this.scaffoldKey});

    @override
    _MessageHandlerState createState() => _MessageHandlerState();
    }
class _MessageHandlerState extends State<MessageHandler>{
    final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
    @override
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _fcm.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("here");
    print("onMessage: $message");
    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message['notification']['title']),
    );

    // reference the scaffold with its key and call showSnackBar
    widget.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackbar(snackbar);
  },
 );
```

Then define the scaffold's key somewhere it can be passed to the message handler and the scaffold:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

....

```
Scaffold(
   key: scaffoldKey,
...
```

More info:

[Display SnackBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579879/display-snackbar-in-flutter)

Comment: I have implemented your solution, however the method `showSnackbar` is not defined, and I'm unsure as to how that method should look.

Comment: Sorry, i think I made an omission, you might need to define the type of the global key as a scaffold key in order to call the showSnackBar method.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand

Comment: does it work if you say  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey; in the MessageHandler?

Comment: Thanks! That line did need to change.